# Application WorkbookOpen Event On Active UserForm

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I'm going to try to summarize it. (Excel 2013)

I have created a Form+VBA project that does the following when you open the File: I check to see if it is the only workbook and if it is not then I remind the user to use a shortcut that I created that opens the file on its own instance. If it is on its own instance, It launches a Form, it makes the form unmovable, it also cancels the X button. Pretty much an "always on top of this instance of excel" form.

```
Private WithEvents App As Application
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
    If Application.Workbooks.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Please use the shortcut to open this file"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Wb.Close False
    Else
        Set App = Application
        UserForm1.Show
    End If
End Sub
```

I added triggers/event that when you open a New Workbook or an Existing workbook on the same instance it closes them and it opens them on a separate instance. Again this is because the form is "always on top".

```
Private Sub App_NewWorkbook(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Set cwb = ThisWorkbook
    If Wb.Name <> cwb.Name Then
        Dim exDir As String, opFile As Variant
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Wb.Close False
        exDir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE"
        opFile = Shell("""" & exDir & """ /X", vbNormalFocus)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Set cwb = ThisWorkbook
    If Wb.Name <> cwb.Name Then
        Dim fDir, exDir As String, opFile As Variant
        fDir = Wb.Path & "\" & Wb.Name
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Wb.Close False
        exDir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE"
        opFile = Shell("""" & exDir & """ /X """ & fDir & """", vbNormalFocus)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
End Sub
```

It works fine, up to a point.

Here is the issue: When the UserForm is closed, both triggers/events work fine for when you open a New Workbook or an Existing File, when the UserForm is active only the trigger for the New Workbook works. If I try to open another excel file it tries to open the file on the existing instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after fighting with it for more time I figured out the problem. When the form is active and you want to open an existing file, excel doesn't let the new file Open at all, therefore it never triggers the WorkbookOpen event, because the form is open. The NewWorkbook event works fine because is triggered when excel tries to open a NewWorkbook.

The way I got this to be fixed is by Allowing interaction between the Form and Excel using the **vbModeless property on the UserForm1.Show command**. This allows the excel window to be used while having the UserForm opened. Since I am making the form unmovable, non closable and I also resize excel to the same size as the form, this works for me. Now all evens trigger because the main Excel window can do everything, and therefore it triggers the WorkbookOpen events as well.